# Styling a disabled input with css only

Tags: html, css

I have sort of a strange situation. I'm trying to style a disabled input button because I have an annoying hover turning the text to white. This makes it  confusing to the user because its acting like a normal button.

I have tried a few things, mainly css and a few jQuery things. I would like to keep this in css if at all posable.

This is my html, sorry it is in a larvel form helper.

```
{{ Form::submit('Change', array_merge($design_project->is_locked ? ['disabled' => 'disabled'] : [], ['class' => 'btn btn-blue span3'])) }}
```

and this is what the browser generates

```
<input disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-blue span3" type="submit" value="Change">
```

and I was working on something like this

```
.btn:hover input[disabled], .btn:active input[disabled], .btn:focus input[disabled]{
  color:green
}
```

Any help would be wonderful!

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML, please?

Comment: @Vector Does the text change its color to green if you hover over the button?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use this CSS ([jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5vnHX/446/)):

```
input:disabled.btn:hover,
input:disabled.btn:active,
input:disabled.btn:focus {
  color: green
}
```

You have to write the most outer element on the left and the most inner element on the right.

`.btn:hover input:disabled` would select any disabled input elements contained in an element with a class `btn` which is currently hovered by the user.

I would prefer `:disabled` over `[disabled]`, see this question for a discussion: [Should I use CSS :disabled pseudo-class or [disabled] attribute selector or is it a matter of opinion?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20141450/603003)

---

By the way, Laravel (PHP) generates the HTML - not the browser.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly for me. Me and my silly spaces! :)

Comment: Are there any reasons for preference between using `[disabled]` and `:disabled` ? (which is also chainable → https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/d/disabled/ )

Comment: @FrankNocke Indeed, :disabled seems to be more preferable, see my edit.

Answer (score 19):

Let's just say you have 3 buttons:

```html
<input type="button" disabled="disabled" value="hello world">
<input type="button" disabled value="hello world">
<input type="button" value="hello world">
```

To style the disabled button you can use the following css:

```css
input[type="button"]:disabled{
    color:#000;
}
```

This will only affect the button which is disabled.

To stop the color changing when hovering you can use this too:

```
input[type="button"]:disabled:hover{
    color:#000;
}
```

You can also avoid this by using a css-reset.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  It's a perfectly valid solution for modern browsers.

Comment: thanks mate. i was about to start thinking that my whole CSS career is a lie :)

Comment: @thesaadarshad I just received an upvote on my answer on this question. By accident I also saw your answer, which I downvoted for a reason I can't remember anymore. I made an edit to be able to revert the downvote. +1!

Comment: `:disabled` doesn't seem to work in IE9. `[disabled]` works.

Answer (score 1):

A space in a CSS selector selects child elements.

```
.btn input
```

This is basically what you wrote and it would select `<input>` elements within any element that has the `btn` class.

I think you're looking for

```
input[disabled].btn:hover, input[disabled].btn:active, input[disabled].btn:focus
```

This would select `<input>` elements with the `disabled` attribute and the `btn` class in the three different states of `hover`, `active` and `focus`.