# Button type CSS and disabled button styling

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

This is an example of my buttons:

```
<button id="question_1a" disabled">Next question</button>
```

I want to have styling for buttons as standard, then a different `background-color` if they are disabled:

```
input[type=button][disabled]{
    background-color:#CCC;
}
input[type=button]{
    background-color: #6CB300;
    color:#fff;
    border:0;
    font-size:1.5em;
    padding:2% 3%;
}
```

This doesn't seem to be correct, how do I select disabled buttons and normal buttons?

Comment: Francesca, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141450/should-i-use-css-disabled-pseudo-class-or-disabled-attribute-selector-or-is-i) may help to clarify the difference between `:disabled` pseudo-class and `[disabled]` attribute selector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you should remove the extra quote `"` at the end of the `<button>` opening tag:

```
<button id="question_1a" disabled">Next question</button>
<!--                      Here --^                    -->
```

Second, Since you are using `<button>` element you should use `button[disabled]` selector in order to select the disabled button.

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/qowimipa/1/edit)**.

```css
button[disabled] {
    background-color:#CCC;
}
```

However there is a pseudo-class called [`:disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3adisabled) which represents any disabled element. You could use `button:disabled` selector to achieve the same result:

```css
button:disabled {
    background-color:#CCC;
}
```

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/qowimipa/3/edit)**.

From the **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3adisabled)**:

> The `:disabled` CSS pseudo-class represents any disabled element. An
>   element is disabled if it can't be activated (e.g. selected, clicked
>   on or accept text input) or accept focus. The element also has an
>   enabled state, in which it can be activated or accept focus.

It's worth noting that `:disabled` pseudo-class is supported in IE9+

Answer (score 3):

You would select them like this:

```
input[type=button]:disabled{
    background-color:#CCC;
}
input[type=button]{
    background-color: #6CB300;
    color:#fff;
    border:0;
    font-size:1.5em;
    padding:2% 3%;
}
```

Also, your HTML has an extra quotation mark.  It should be:

```
<button id="question_1a" disabled>Next question</button>
```

Comment: I tried this but weirdly it doesn't seem to be styling my buttons at all: http://francesca-designed.me/quiz/quiz.php

Comment: You're not targeting your buttons.  You're targeting inputs that have the type button.  You would need to change your CSS to style buttons instead of inputs for it to work.  Also, you should look at Hashem Qolami's answer for more clarification.

Answer (score 2):

```
input[type="button"]:disabled {}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your html you have a `<button>` element, but in your selector you match `<input>`.

Then, change your html to [[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BNhNU/1/)]

```
<input type="button" id="question_1a" disabled="disabled" value="Next question" />
```

or change your css to [[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BNhNU/)]

```
button{ /* ... */ }
button[disabled]{ /* ... */ }
```

---

Anyway, note that if you use `<button>` elements you should set `type="button"` to them too, in order to avoid buggy behavior in some browsers.

And you could use `:disabled` pseudo class instead of the attribute selector.