# Select child element of element with attribute

Tags: css, html, attributes, css-selectors

I have a button.  The button has a span tag inside of it for the text of the button.  Sometimes the button may be disabled.  When disabled, I'd like the button to be grey.  Why 
doesn't this work?  First the HTML, then the CSS

```
<button disabled>
    <span class="dark-disabled">Start New Game</span>
</button>

button:disabled span{
    background: #ccc;
}
```

But it will fire if I do a class selector instead:

```
button:disabled .dark-disabled{
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the CSS [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```
button[disabled] span{
  background: #ccc;
}
```

## Edit:

I misread your question, both `:disabled` and `[disabled]` will work for a button.
The sample you gave me works fine in Firefox: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gKCz2/)

What browser are you using?

Comment: Depending on the browsers you are catering towards, consider reading up on `normalize.css`

Comment: See also the difference between the two http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141450/should-i-use-css-disabled-pseudo-class-or-disabled-attribute-selector-or-is-i

Answer (score 0):

All browsers, including IE8 and up, automatically give disabled buttons a different gray background. Just use this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Start new game</button>
    <button disabled="disabled">Start new game</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Which will give the most consistent visual result across browsers as well.