# CSS rules for multiple attributes

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to set some CSS rules for an input button of `type` `submit`, which does not have `disabled` set to `true`, and which has the `hover` selector enabled.

The following syntax doesn't quite work for me:

```
input[type="submit"]:hover[disabled~="true"]:hover
```

What's the solution?

Comment: What do you mean by “not have `disabled` set to `true`"? The valid values of the HTML attribute `disabled` are the string `disabled` (case insensitively) and the empty string. Do you actually refer to setting the `disabled` *property* of the element node to `true` in JavaScript or via an HTML attribute? A different question, with a rather different answer.

Answer (score 3):

`~=` does not mean "is not equal to", despite the `~`. It means [something different entirely](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-representation) (but what it specifically means is outside the scope of this question).

The `disabled` attribute in HTML is a Boolean attribute, which means it doesn't have a specific value *per se* (unless you're talking about XHTML, but that's a different matter entirely). You're probably looking for an input that does not have the attribute at all, as opposed to it having a value that is not `true`. In which case, you would use:

```
input[type="submit"]:hover:not([disabled])
```

Better yet, if you can afford the browser compatibility, [use the `:disabled` pseudo-class instead of an attribute selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141450/should-i-use-css-disabled-pseudo-class-or-disabled-attribute-selector-or-is-i/20146936#20146936) so you do not have to worry about possible attribute values:

```
input[type="submit"]:hover:not(:disabled)
```

(Note that I've also removed the extraneous `:hover` at the end of your selector which I presume was a mistake.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
input[type="submit"]:enabled:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

Note that IE<9 does not support the `enabled` selector.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LT3S5/) for an example.