# CSS selector for disabled elements

Tags: html, angularjs, css

I'm working with AngularJS to set image buttons disabled/enabled.
My css selector to show them transparent isn't working.
I've started with a [try it](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_enabled_disabled2) that selects a disable on an input element and there it does indeed apply the css, but not in case of my div elements.
I've added my div elements that don't work, resulting in the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
input:enabled {
    background: #ffff00;
}

input:disabled {
    background: #dddddd;
}
div:disabled {
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form action="">
First name: <input type="text" value="Mickey"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" value="Mouse"><br>
Country: <input type="text" value="Disneyland" disabled><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="psw" disabled><br>
E-mail: <input type="email" value="john@doe.com" name="usremail">
</form>
<div disabled="disabled">should be transparent</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The disabled is getting added/removed for my AngularJS html elements. So how do I get the css to apply to a div with disabled added to it?

Note: I know it's possible to duplicate the elements, use ng-if to show/hide them and apply the transparency to it with a class, but that's very ugly.

Comment: but I don't get why you need `disabled` attribute for `div`s - its for form elements...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`:disabled` pseudo selector will work only for input elements. For div, use `div[disabled]` to apply css

Use

```
div[disabled] {
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

**Demo**

```css
input:enabled {
    background: #ffff00;
}

input:disabled {
    background: #dddddd;
}
div[disabled] {
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

```html
<form action="">
First name: <input type="text" value="Mickey"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" value="Mouse"><br>
Country: <input type="text" value="Disneyland" disabled><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="psw" disabled><br>
E-mail: <input type="email" value="john@doe.com" name="usremail">
</form>
<div disabled="disabled">should be transparent</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Select all **disabled input elements** (such as input, textarea, select, option, radio, checkbox, button) :

```
*:disabled{
    //enter code here
}
```

Select all **other disabled elements** (such as div, section, p, etc):

```
*[disabled]{
    //enter code here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the attribute selector `[attribute='value']`, which will work on all types of elements, compared to the pseudo-class `:disabled`, which only works on form elements

And in your case, where the attribute `disabled` doesn't have a value, you can omit it `[disabled]`

*Note, when not using the value part in the selector, it will target elements both with and without, but as you can see the with last CSS rule, where the value part is used, it won't.*

Stack snippet *(here I used it on all, but you can of course keep `:disabled` for the `input`'s)*

```css
input:not([disabled]) {
  background: #ffff00;
}

input[disabled] {
  background: #dddddd;
}

div[disabled] {
  opacity: 0.4;
  filter: alpha(opacity=40);      /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

div[disabled='disabled'] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  First name: <input type="text" value="Mickey"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" value="Mouse"><br>
  Country: <input type="text" value="Disneyland" disabled><br>
  Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="psw" disabled><br>
  E-mail: <input type="email" value="john@doe.com" name="usremail">
</form>

<div disabled>
  should be transparent, but doesn't have red colored text
</div>

<div disabled='disabled'>
  this will both be transparent and have red colored text
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For a div element you should use `div[disabled="disabled"]` or `div[disabled]`

its not an input element where you can apply `:disabled`

Answer (score 2):

You can use **div[disabled="disabled"]** to select disabled div.

Answer (score 1):

See Below Example :

```css
input:enabled {
    background: #ffff00;
}

input:disabled {
    background: #dddddd;
}
div:disabled {
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

```html
<form action="">
First name: <input type="text" value="Mickey"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" value="Mouse"><br>
Country: <input type="text" value="Disneyland" disabled><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="psw" disabled><br>
E-mail: <input type="email" value="john@doe.com" name="usremail">
</form>
<input disabled/>should be transparent
```

And aslo See this :

[image]

Comment: I tried removing the string attribute part, it didn't work. Did you test this out?

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
*:disabled, *[disabled]{ /* ... */}
```

**Example**

```css
*:disabled,
*[disabled] {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="foo" disabled />
<input type="text" value="bar" />
```