# CSS `:disable` vs `[disabled]`

Tags: css, css-selectors

I was looking in a projects source code and found something like this,

```
input[disabled] {
  /* ... */
}
```

Note: it works

Instead of,

```
input:disabled {
  /* ... */
}
```

But,

- why [`[disabled]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) attribute selector instead of [`:disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled) pseudo selector ?
- Whats  the benefit of using either one ?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: This reference link will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20146936/8202850

Comment: Derek.W & JohnMontgomery  yep, i got it, Thanks a lot :)