# :required or [required] CSS selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

Browsing the MDN docs to see the status of a proposed pseudo-class, I came across `:required` (and by extension, `:optional`). Both of these have been around for a long time but I've only just learnt about them now.

How does this selector differ from using the attribute selector, `[required]`. Does it differ?

`input:required` or `input[required]`. I'll admit that `input:optional` is nicer than `input:not([required])`.

If it doesn't differ in any way, which should be used or does it not matter at all? Why were these two introduced when attribute selectors are around?

Comment: Same reason as :disabled vs [disabled] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141450/should-i-use-css-disabled-pseudo-class-or-disabled-attribute-selector-or-is-i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
input:required {
  border-color: blue;
}

input[required] {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" required>
```

> Does it differ?

It doesn't really look like they differ functionally.

> If it doesn't differ in any way, which should be used or does it not matter at all?

Functionally, I do not think it makes any difference. However,

> Why were these two introduced when attribute selectors are around?

Along with pseudo-classes like `:valid` and :`invalid`, `:required` and `:optional` provide a consistent way to write css for `form` elements. I believe that was the intended purpose (from no source whatsoever, just my assumption).

As you also mentioned, it does help with reducing verbosity such as `:not([required])`.

Comment: One very minor difference is that `:required` and `:optional` only match form elements. `:not([required])` could match other elements like `<div>`s. I guess `[required]` could match non-form elements too, though as of writing that'd imply invalid html.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:required

> The :required CSS pseudo-class represents **any <input>, <select>, or
> <textarea>** element that has the required attribute set on it.

Therefore:

```css
:required {
  border: 2px solid #f00;
}
```

selects:

```html
<input type="text" required />
```

but doesn't select:

```html
<div required>
test
</div>
```

Though:

```css
[required] {
  border: 2px solid #f00;
}
```

selects:

```html
<div required>
test
</div>
```

## Edited

Though a `DIV` element having a `required` attribute:

- Nevertheless, CSS selects it and the element is rendered accordingly. That's a difference.
- It's possible to make custom elements ([Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components)) which might have `required` attributes. It seems YouTube has several web components. Frameworks, like [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html), [React.js](https://reactjs.org/docs/web-components.html) and [Angular](https://angular.io/guide/elements) support web components. We might use external components with web components.
- CSS is not only used for HTML. It's also used for XML. For instance, SVG.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS

> Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) is a stylesheet language used to describe
> the presentation of a document written **in HTML or XML** (including XML
> dialects such as **SVG, MathML or XHTML**). CSS describes how elements
> should be rendered on screen, on paper, in speech, or on other media.

Comment: `div[required]` is currently invalid HTML so I would currently dismiss that, however, that doesn't dismiss the possibility of it ever becoming valid.

Comment: Despite that, it rendered with a red border. Therefore, `:required` and `[required]` are different, and I explained how (citing documentation and providing examples), answering the question appropriately. They would be only the same if there wasn't any difference. By the way: CSS is not only used for HTML. It's also used, for instance, for XML. Especially, in SVG. Therefore, saying they don't differ is incorrect.

Comment: There are also custom HTML elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements