# disabled text input not styling

Tags: html, css

I have a form with disabled text input fields that I would like to style to look normal but not allow input.

Works in Chrome, but not in FireFox or IE - is this something that can be done in FF/IE?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="test" disabled />
```

CSS:

```
input[type="text"][disabled] {
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling a disabled input with css only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445543/styling-a-disabled-input-with-css-only)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```css
input[type="text"][disabled],
input[type="text"]:disabled {
    color: #ff0;
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="test" disabled />
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonsuh/brbktnvv/

Comment: Works fine in Chrome, doesn't work in IE11/FF. Is this normal?