# Disable the postback of asp.net button

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My idea is when the user isn't loged in he won't be able to add an item to the shopping cart, so what I did is like so:

```
<asp:Button ID="BTNAddToCart" runat="server" Text="Add to cart" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" style="display: inline; margin: auto; display: block; visibility: hidden;"  OnClick="BTNAddToCart_Click" />
```

And then on code behind:

```
if (Session["User"] == null)
{
    BTNAddToCart.Attributes["class"] = "btn btn-info btn-lg disabled";
    BTNAddToCart.Attributes.Add("title", "Error");  
    BTNAddToCart.Attributes.Add("data-toggle", "popover");
    BTNAddToCart.Attributes.Add("data-trigger", "hover");
    BTNAddToCart.Attributes.Add("data-placement", "bottom");
    BTNAddToCart.Attributes.Add("data-content", "You must be loged in to add items to the cart");  
}
```

As You can see, by using Bootstrap I gave the button the look which he can't be clicked, but in reality He is still clickable.

So I thought that mabey if I will disable the button postback it will really be not clickable.

**How can I disable the button postback?**

I have tried:

```
<asp:Button ID="BTNAddToCart" runat="server" Text="Add to cart" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" style="display: inline; margin: auto; display: block; visibility: hidden;" OnClientClick="BTNJavaScriptClick()" OnClick="BTNAddToCart_Click" />



<script>  

function BTNJavaScriptClick()
{
    var ButtonAdd = document.getElementById("BTNAddToCart");
    if (ButtonAdd.className == "btn btn-info btn-lg disabled") 
        return false;
}

 </script>
```

I even tried `BTNAddToCart.Enabled = false;` and it worked but it made my popover disapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the button to react when the mouse is over it (e.g. show a tooltip) while not triggering a postback when clicked, you can:

- Keep the button enabled
- Show the button as disabled with the BootStrap style
- Prevent the postback by returning `false` in `OnClientClick`
- Prevent the button from getting the focus

The code would look like this:

```
if (Session["User"] == null)
{
    BTNAddToCart.CssClass = "btn btn-info btn-lg disabled";
    BTNAddToCart.OnClientClick = "return false;";
    BTNAddToCart.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "this.blur();");
    ...
}
```

Comment: I actually love you! I have been sitting on this for hours!

Answer (score 3):

You can simple set **Enable** asp.net attribute to false and the button will not post back.

```
BTNAddToCart.Enabled = false;
```

When an element is `disabled` you can use the `disabled` style on css to give him the desired look. Here is a simple example:

```
input:disabled {
    background: #444;
}
```

relative to that:
[Styling a disabled input with css only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445543/styling-a-disabled-input-with-css-only)

Comment: One more thing, by doing that it cancelled the "style" I gave the button (The popover) how can I make both oh them work?

Comment: @harel486 see the style with the :disabled on css http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_disabled.asp  and please vote and accept the answer if works for you

Comment: The thing is after puting the `BTNAddToCart.Enabled = false;` I can't change class via code behind...

Comment: @harel486 Yes you can, but because is disabled is follow some other set on the css. Just let the class as it is to see what is happens - bootstrap have take care of the disabled elements

Comment: Can you show me how by writing a bit of the css code? I want the popover to work if the `BTNAddToCart.Enabled = true;`

Comment: @harel486 I have write you and a sample and give you 2 links. In bootstrap is little more difficult to make it work, but try and you find it